# How to ask Mathematica to start $x$ axis from $1$, not $0$ in a plot with frame?

Tags: plotting, frame

I use this code

```
data = Table[{x, 6/x (Csc[30 x])^2}, {x, 1, 6}];
ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "f"}]
```

and the result is

[image]

How can I ask Mathematica to start the $x$ axis from $1$, not $0$?

[image]

Comment: Add an option like `PlotRange -> {{1, All}, Automatic}`. And maybe ``PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02`], Scaled[0.02`]}, {Scaled[0.02`],  Scaled[0.05`]}}``

Comment: `data = Table[{x, 6/x (Csc[30 x])^2}, {x, 1, 6}];
ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "f"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way (in the sense that `ListLogPlot` figures out the plot range automatically) is just `PlotRange -> All`:

```
ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "f"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Another use case (see updated question) requires overriding the default `Ticks`:

```
data = Table[{x, 6/x (Csc[30 x])^2}, {x, 1, 5999}];
ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "f"}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, 
         Identity}][##] /. {0., _, s__} :> {1., 1, s} &, 
    Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] /. {0., t_, 
        s__} :> {1., t, s} &}}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}]
```

[image]

This works with the first example, too.

Comment: @charmin Example?

Comment: @charmin That's from the plot range padding.  Do you really want the first point on the left to land on the frame?  But not the last point on the right?  Usually a little space around the plot is desirable.  (Consider `{x, 1, 5999}` and looks at both ends: Do you not want to see the `6000` tick mark?)

Comment: @charmin Do you want the 6000 to show if the last data point is 5999?

Comment: @ Michael E2 Yes, if possible, I want both $1$ and $6000$ to show, if it is not possible, at least to show $1$ in the begining.

Comment: @charmin See update.

Comment: @charmin They're blue in my version, too.  Tricky little devils, changing version to version.  They've been around for a while.  Search the sight.  See update.  I think the new edit works in both 12.0, 12.1.1

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, now it works :)

Answer (score 4):

Try `PlotRange`

```
ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True,FrameLabel -> {"x", "f"}, PlotRange -> {{1, Automatic}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`PlotRangePadding` work.

```
data = Table[{x, 6/x (Csc[30 x])^2}, {x, 1, 6}]; ListLogPlot[data, 
 Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "f"},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.01]
```